# improper integration of a cosine function

Tags: integration, trigonometry, convergence-divergence, improper-integrals

> Prove that $\int_0^\infty{\cos{(t^\alpha)}dt}$ converges when $\alpha>1$.

I tried to use the Taylor theorem to expand the cosine as $\cos{(t^\alpha)}=\sum_{n=1}^\infty{\frac{(-1)^{n}{t}^{2\alpha n}}{(2n)!}} \leq \sum_{n=1}^\infty{\frac{{t}^{2\alpha n}}{(2n)!}} \leq \cosh{(t^\alpha)}$, but didn't work at all since the integral of the hyperbolic cosine will diverge.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write
$$\int_0^\infty \cos(t^\alpha)\,dt=\int_0^1\cos(t^\alpha)\,dt+\int_1^\infty \cos(t^\alpha)\,dt$$
The first integral is finite. Substitute $u=t^\alpha$ in the second integral to convert it to an integral in $u$. Then integrate by parts and show the result is finite (must compute a limit and do a comparison test).